# User (com.informix.asf.IfxASFRemoteException: )'s password is not correct for the database server

Tags: jdbc, informix

I am trying to connect to a remote Informix database from my Java application using JDBC. However, I always get an error as mentioned in the title of this topic.

I double checked the password field and that is correct. The code I am trying to connect is pretty straight forward and is as follows:

Class.forName("com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver");
        this.Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, UserName, Password);
        return Connection;

It is a simple JAVA web application deployed on Tomcat.

Please help.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Have you double checked if the connectionURL is correct? Maybe you are asking  another DB that uses another password.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same issue and resolved it. The issue is that informix database expects a strict adherence to the database url, white spaces are not ignored in the url. This is the format that works for me:
jdbc:informix-sqli://server:port/db:INFORMIXSERVER=server;user=usr;password=pass

Note: usr is the the database username and pass is the password to the account